# Chuck App Data Base

Tags: java, android, database

This is a bit of a strange question but I downloaded the source code from the link below.

http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.ie/2011/06/getting-started-complete-android-app.html

I've changed the database but it doesn't seem to change the questions. Does anyone know how to change the questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem.  I edited the database in sqlite browser (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) and then I uninstalled the app from the eclipse emulator(open the emulator and go to setting, apps and then uninstall).  Then in the project I replaced the database in the assets folder with the one i'd edited in sqlite.  This brought up my questions. Happy F**king days!!!! :-) Hope this helps someone else if they have this problem.  Any questions just ask...... and i'll try help you.